# Difference between parenthesis placements for array of points in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am studying C on my own and I am very confused on why

```
int b[2][3];
int (*p)[3] = b;
```

is different from

```
int b[2][3];
int *p[3] = b;
```

Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a pointer to an array, while the other is an array of pointers.

This:

```
int (*p)[3]
```

Is a pointer to an array of size 3 of `int`.  This means `*p` gives you the array and `(*p)[1]` gets the element at index 1 of that array.

It is also allowed to assign `b` to this pointer.  This is because `b` is an array of size 2 whose members are an array of size 3 of `int`, and arrays decay to a pointer to their first element in an expression, so `b` decays from type `int[2][3]` to type `int(*)[3]` which matches `p`.  So you can also for example use `p[1][2]` to access the same array element as `b[1][2]`.

In contrast, this:

```
int *p[3]
```

Is an array of size 3 whose members are `int *`.  Attempting to assign `b` to this won't work because you can't assign to an array directly and because the types are not compatible.

You could however do this:

```
int x[5], y[4], y[6];
p[0] = x;
p[1] = y;
p[2] = z;
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!